# In SMTP, must the RCPT TO: and TO: match?

Tags: email, smtp, protocols

When sending an email, the recipient list is given during the SMTP dialogue through RCTP TO: command. Later, in DATA command, header fields like 'To', 'Cc','bcc' are indicated. Does this RCPT TO list of recipients have to match with the headers indicated in DATA command?

Also, if the recipient is not indicated in RCPT TO, but in the To field of email header, is it going to be delivered to the recipient not in RCPT TO?

Comment: Hi @Razzle, I think it's OK now. Feel free to delete your comment (I will delete mine as well)

Answer (score 24):

No, they don't have to match. When the message is sent, the SMTP Server (aka Message Transfer Agent or MTA) is creating a so called SMTP envelope which contains the recipients and the sender of the message (see [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.1)):

> SMTP transports a mail object.  A mail object contains an envelope   and content.   The SMTP envelope is sent as a series of SMTP protocol
> units   (described in Section 3).  It consists of an originator
> address (to   which error reports should be directed), one or more
> recipient   addresses, and optional protocol extension material.

It is, actually, quite often that the RCPT TO: Command has more recipients that the header of the message - one common case is the usage of "blind copies" bcc: (see [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.1)):

> Addresses that do not appear in the message header section may appear
> in the RCPT commands to an SMTP server for a number of reasons.  The
> two most common involve the use of a mailing address as a "list
> exploder" (a single address that resolves into multiple addresses) and
> the appearance of "blind copies".

Comment: Minor nitpick: RFC5321 says MTA is an abbreviation for "Mail Transfer Agent", not "Message Transfer Agent"

Answer (score 15):

> Does this RCPT TO list of recipients have to match with the headers
> indicated in DATA command?

Nope.

> if the recipient is not indicated in RCPT TO, but in the To field of
> email header, is it going to be delivered to the recipient not in RCPT
> TO ?

The RCPT.  Here's a (modified) transcript from my own SMTP client where I do just what you ask:

```
CLIENT: MAIL FROM:<myaccount@gmail.com>
SERVER: 250 2.1.0 OK 
CLIENT: RCPT TO:<myaccount@gmail.com>
SERVER: 250 2.1.5 OK 
CLIENT: DATA
SERVER: 354  Go ahead 
CLIENT: Subject: Test email
CLIENT: From:'John Doe'<fakeaccount@gmail.com>
CLIENT: To:'John Doe'<fakeaccount@gmail.com>
CLIENT: This is a test...
CLIENT: .
```

The message was successfully sent to "myaccount@gmail.com".

Comment: BTW, the IMF fields (To, From) may show up in your email client, so that it appears to coming from and/or being sent to the wrong address.

Answer (score 6):

SMTP protocol ([RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)) states the following:

> When RFC 822 format [7, 32] is being used, the mail data include the
>   memo header items such as Date, Subject, To, Cc, From.  Server SMTP
>   systems SHOULD NOT reject messages based on perceived defects in the
>   RFC 822 or MIME [12] message header or message body.

And this:

> The DATA    command can fail at only two points in the protocol
>   exchange:
>
> - If there was no MAIL, or no RCPT, command, or all such commands
>       were rejected, the server MAY return a "command out of sequence"
>       (503) or "no valid recipients" (554) reply in response to the DATA
>       command.  If one of those replies (or any other 5yz reply) is
>       received, the client MUST NOT send the message data; more
>       generally, message data MUST NOT be sent unless a 354 reply is
>       received.

From these statements, the headers and RCPT TO: command content does not have to match (altough they should match), and not using RCPT TO: MAY result in an error to prevent proceeding with DATA command.

Comment: and what about a case when RCPT and To: do not match. Who is the actual recipient in this case?

Comment: @Jelena, I believe it's the RCPT that's all that matters and the `To:` can be random data.